# Where can I download an Everway character sheet?

Tags: character-sheets, everway

I've dug up my old Everway set for a game I'm running this weekend, and realised that I can't find my character sheets.  I can easily improvise one, but Everway's weirdly beautiful sheets are part of the fun.  Is there anywhere I can download a colour scan of the sheet?

(A printable greyscale PDF or black and white scan is an acceptable fallback if colour is impossible, but I *like* the full colour sheets.)

Comment: Looks like a fascinating game, mate. If you want to drop by The Back Room and demo it for me/us, I'd be delighted to give it a spin.

Comment: I'd love to, @Brian.  I'm busy this weekend helping friends paint their house (although apparently running Everway is a major part of my house-painting duties...); I'd be glad to run this some time soon - I'll drop a message when I get back and we can arrange something.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I scanned in one of my Everway character sheets and prepared three PDFs, at [300dpi (6.2MB)](http://everway.oxif.org/EverwayCharacterSheetColourLetter300dpi.pdf), [150dpi (1.6MB)](http://everway.oxif.org/EverwayCharacterSheetColourLetter150dpi.pdf) and [75dpi (412KB)](http://everway.oxif.org/EverwayCharacterSheetColourLetter075dpi.pdf).

I also uploaded the 75dpi and 150dpi images to the [Everway](https://groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/Everway-L/files/Everway%20Tools/Everway%20Sheets/) yahoo group that [Brian](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/760) mentioned. Unfortunately, at the time they had a file size limit of 5120KB, so I had to host the highest resolution sheet myself. Since then the file size limit has increased, so [Longspeak](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/15522) was able to complete the set there too.

<sup>The scan of the original WOTC character sheet is reproduced without permission but is assumed to be allowed under fair use.</sup>

Comment: Excellent! Glad to see you updated stuff. Please, ask more questions about everway so we can preserve the tag.

Comment: I hardly see correcting a typo as being of huge value, but I do have perfectionist tendencies. 8') I just wish there was a way to tell SE that a change is trivial and thus not *bump* it.

Comment: Mark, I added the 300 dpi scan to the Everway group, crediting your username in the comment. Size limits have changed since then (I assume), and that lovely scan deserves to be there.

Comment: Thanks @Longspeak, I've updated my answer to mention that.

Answer (score 3):

- [Black and White Character Sheet, Official](https://netfiles.uiuc.edu/rwb/www/gaming/everweb/EverChar.pdf)
- [Ancient HTML character sheet](http://www.morat.demon.co.uk/Everway/template.html)
- [5 Character sheets, one in Full Colour with vector graphics](http://games.groups.yahoo.com/group/Everway-L/files/Everway%20Sheets/) (requires joining the Yahoo Group)
- [A slightly less atrocious HTML sheet (Warning, comic sans)](http://www.highclearing.com/amberway/chartemplate.html)

I particularly recommend the [everway_character_sheet_(SAJ).png](http://f1.grp.yahoofs.com/v1/EPKvTbKsaRnKQf_s8LiUiNHjJ4yh8TnWiTiVMGQHx0LYXgIQM8KI267XV74ju3MDc95nlp85ryoI-SYnJoMr4q-ljcdO/Everway%20Sheets/everway_character_sheet_%28SAJ%29.png) (yahoo group membership required) as it's just beautiful.

Comment: The SAJ sheet *is* kinda cool, although I still think it's not nearly as beautiful as the original.  (If I ever do find my originals I'll have to scan & upload.)  Thanks.